# How can i prove $X_{n}$ is a markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $X_0,Y_1,Y_2,...$ be i.i.d r.vs such that $X_0$ takes values from $\{0,1,...,\}$, whilst $Y_i$ is distributed by $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1)=\frac{1}{i}, \mathbb{P}(Y_i=0)=1-\frac{1}{i}$ where $i\ge 1$. Then show that $X_n$ is a Markov Chain such that

> $$ X_{n+1} :=
> \begin{cases} 
>       \max\{\{k:1\le k \le X_n~~ \text{and}~~ Y_k=1\}\} & X_n>1 \\
>       0 & X_n\ge 1 
>    \end{cases}$$

I'm wondering what a general method of proving Markov Chains? Is it by using the conditional probability rule and getting to an end result? I'm not sure how to proceed here...
$$P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|X_0=i_0,...,X_{n}=i_{n})=\frac{P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1})}{P(X_0=i_0,...,X_{n}=i_{n})} = \frac{P(\{Max(k,Y_k=1)\}=i_{n+1})}{P(X_0=i_0,...,X_{n}=i_{n})} $$

Answer (score 1):

Btw, I'm assuming you have a typo in your expression for $X_{n+1}$; specifically that $X_{n+1}=0$ for $X_n\leq 1$.

Let $X_n = \alpha_{n}$ for some non-negative integer $\alpha_n$.

If $\alpha_n \leq 1$,

$P(X_{n+1}=q) :=
\begin{cases} 
      1, q = 0\\
      0, otherwise 
   \end{cases}$

Else
$P(X_{n+1}=q) :=
\begin{cases} 
      P(Y_q=1,Y_{q+1}=0,Y_{q+2}=0...Y_{\alpha_n}=0), \forall 1\leq q \leq \alpha_n\\
      0, otherwise 
   \end{cases}$

where $P(Y_q=1,Y_{q+1}=0,Y_{q+2}=0...Y_{\alpha_n}) = \frac{1}{\alpha_n}$

Thus the probability distribution of $X_{n+1}$ depends only on what values $X_n$ takes on.